# JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have data on this string, but I'm having trouble to access the individual data. 
This is my code:

```
Log.d("Detail Outputss", "" + response.toString());
```

And this is the string output:

```
{"futsal_id":"45","info":[{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_name":"Kathmandu Futsal","city":"Kathmandu","address":"Kathmandu","owner_name":"Hari Prasad","owner_address":"Kathmandu","email":"kathmandufutsal@gmail.com","password":"kathmandu","phone_no":"1111111","mobile_no":"9841112233","status":"1"}],"description":[{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_desc":"Futsal is the fever which never ends.\r\nKathmandu futsal is - a platform, a medium of communication for our fraternity. Not just somewhere to host challenges or seek venues, but a place where we can all share and spread the luv! Here, you can find just about anything, do just about anything, and see just about anything. Unbelievable? Believe it."}],"features":[{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_feat":"Free Wifi"},{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_feat":"High Quality Grass"},{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_feat":"Canteen Facility"},{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_feat":"Friendly Environment"}],"dimension":[{"futsal_id":"45","dimension":"40m X 20m"}],"no_of_futsal":[{"futsal_id":"45","number":"1"}],"opening_hrs":[{"futsal_id":"45","open_time_id":"1","open_time":"6am","close_time_id":"15","close_time":"9pm"}],"price_weekdays_price1":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"1","start_time":"6am","end_time":"12pm","price":"1200"}],"price_weekdays_price2":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"2","start_time":"12pm","end_time":"6pm","price":"1000"}],"price_weekdays_price3":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"3","start_time":"6pm","end_time":"9pm","price":"1500"}],"price_weekend_price1":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"1","start_time":"6pm","end_time":"12pm","price":"1500"}],"price_weekend_price2":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"2","start_time":"12pm","end_time":"6pm","price":"1800"}],"price_weekend_price3":[{"futsal_id":"45","price_id":"3","start_time":"6pm","end_time":"9pm","price":"2000"}],"phone_number_address":[{"futsal_id":"45","futsal_name":"Kathmandu Futsal","city":"Kathmandu","address":"Kathmandu","owner_name":"Hari Prasad","owner_address":"Kathmandu","email":"kathmandufutsal@gmail.com","password":"kathmandu","phone_no":"1111111","mobile_no":"9841112233","status":"1"}],"news":[{"futsal_id":"45","news_id":"7","news_title":"asdfasdfasdfasdf","news_description":"asdfashdflahsdlfasdjf;oajsd;ofjaosdijfoaisdjofajsdfja;sjdf;ajsd;fja;ksdjf;kasjd;fkja;sdjf;asjd;fajsd;fjasdjf;asjd;fjas;djf;asdf"},{"futsal_id":"45","news_id":"6","news_title":"awefasdf","news_description":"sdjf;asdf;a;sdf;asjdf;oajsd;fja;sdjf;oajsd;oifjaosdf"},{"futsal_id":"45","news_id":"5","news_title":"asdfasdf","news_description":"sadfasdfasdfasdfa"}]}
```

I want to get the value of each object `futsal_id`, `futsal_name`, city and others, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you share the code until what you have tried? If you don't know how to parse JSON data visit http://www.json.org/java/ or https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: see this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: If you have invested that much time in searching how to parse json, you would have got the idea and you would be settled by yourself parse json.

Answer (score 0):

It is JSONArray within a JSONObject

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray info = json.getJSONArray("info");
//getting the first value.. loop it if you have more than one
JSONObject infoObject = info.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray description = json.getJSONArray("description");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
int fustal_id =Integer.parseInt(json.getString("futsal_id"));
JSONArray inf = json.getJSONArray("info");
JSONObject info = inf.getJSONObject(0);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray info = responseObject.getJSONArray("info");
for(int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) { 
    JSONObject obj = info.getJSONObject(i);
    String futsal_id = obj.getString("futsal_id");
    String futsal_name = obj.getString("futsal_name");
    //so on
}
```

Be sure to catch the [exceptions](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONException.html).